# When will the resignFirstResponder get called?

Tags: ios, first-responder

I am troubleshooting a strange behaviour of a UITextField in my app.

During editing the above textField, if the app goes to the background and comes back to the foreground, the keyboard disappears. I have kept breakpoints at all places where the resignFirstResponder is getting called. But, I am unable to find the cause of the disappearing keyboard.

Is there any instance when the keyboard will be dismissed without specifying resignFirstResponder explicitly in code? 
What is the expected standard behaviour in the above case?

Comment: does `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate getting invoked?

Comment: `endEditing` is other possible reason

Comment: are you testing it on simulator or in actual device because in simulator this can be happen in ios8 but will not be in device